# Calculate the fraction of wins in craps

Tags: python-3.x, count

I want to write a function that takes a positive integer n as input, simulates n craps games, and returns the fraction of games the player won.

the underlying craps simulating code i've written is as follows:

```
import random
def craps():
    dice = random.randrange(1,7) + random.randrange(1,7)
    if dice in (7,11):
        return 1
    if dice in (2,3,12):
        return 0
    newRoll = random.randrange(1,7) + random.randrange(1,7)
    while newRoll not in (7,dice):
        newRoll = random.randrange(1,7) + random.randrange(1,7)
    if newRoll == dice:     
        return 1
    else:
        return  0

import random
def testCraps(n):
    count = 0
    fract = count/n
    games = n*craps()
    for i in range(games):
        if i == 1:
            count +=1
        else:
            pass
    return fract

usage:

>>> fracCraps(10000) 
0.4844
>>> fracCraps(10000)
0.492
```

what i get when I execute is:

```
>>> testCraps(10000)
0.0
```

I just can't get the counter to work.???

Comment: Worth mentioning: you only need `import random` once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting `0` as the result every time because you set `fract = countW/n` when `countW` is `0`. `countW` is **always** `0`, since you reset it each time through the loop. You just want to set it once, at the beginning of the function outside the loop. The same goes for `fract`; you want that to be done at the end (or better yet, just `return countW/n` at the end and eliminate `fract` altogether).

```
import random
def testCraps(n):
    countW = 0
    for i in range(n):
        # The rest of your code
    return countW/n

# Example output
print(testCraps(10000)) # 0.6972
print(testCraps(10000)) # 0.698
```

---

**Edit @new content**

You seem to have edited your question to ask a different question, having only half-implemented the answers given here. You need to make sure you're returning the right thing (`count/n`), and make sure you're calling things inside the loop when you mean to. `n*craps()` is either `n` or `0`, since `craps()` returns just a `1` or a `0`. What you want is, `n` times, call `craps()` and assess the outcome.

```
def testCraps(n):
    count = 0
    for _ in range(n):
        if craps() == 1: # "play" a craps game and check the result
            count +=1
    return count/n

# Example output
print(testCraps(10000)) # 0.4971
print(testCraps(10000)) # 0.4929
```

Comment: i need to call the previous function craps() and count how many times that one is producing 1(win) in n games, and im not sure how to do that

Comment: @Snarre Okay, but why didn't you say that in the first place? You've completely changed your question since I posted this answer--if you solved the problem you originally posted, the correct thing to do is accept an answer and then, if you have a different question, ask a different question separately.

Comment: @Snarre For now, I've edited my answer to solve your second question as well, but in the future, use a new question when you have a new question.

Comment: ok im sorry sir, i did not know how do sepearet my question...sorry. I did not mean to be an inconvinince to anybody, just a bit of a newbee here

Comment: Regarding the code in the edit, you can greatly simplify the test code by using `sum`: `def testCraps(n): return sum(craps() for _ in range(n)) / n`

Comment: @Blckknght Absolutely true; that's actually almost exactly what I wrote over here originally. I decided to break it out into an explicit loop for clarity, since it's a pretty big jump from where the OP is starting.

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of each iteration of your for-loop, you are resetting `countW` to `0`.  Set it to zero once outside the for loop to keep a running count.

You also want to move your calculation of `fract` outside the for loop.  Calculate the `frac` after all the looping is done.